# Просто так заканчиваются итерации

Tags: python, коллекции

есть программа, которой дается список температур за каждый день, надо найти средненедельную температуру, используя дек. Но вот проблемка, сперва все идет хорошо, но на третьей недели алгоритм просто так заканчивается. Хотел посмотреть через отладчик вдруг условие остановки выполняется, но нет, интерпретатор тупо выходит из цикла, как-будто там закончились аргументы, начал выводить список, но элементов там еще полно. В чем проблема? Подскажите, пожалуйста

```
temps = list(reversed([20.6, 19.4, 19.0, 19.0, 22.1,
                        22.5, 22.8, 24.1, 25.6, 27.0,
                        27.0, 25.6, 26.8, 27.3, 22.5,
                        25.4, 24.4, 23.7, 23.6, 22.6,
                        20.4, 17.9, 17.3, 17.3, 18.1,
                        20.1, 22.2, 19.8, 21.3, 21.3,
                        21.9]))
print(temps)
days = deque(maxlen=7)
 
for temp in temps:
    # Добавляем температуру в очередь
    a = temps.pop()
    days.append(a)
    print(days)
    print(temps)
    
    if len(days) == days.maxlen:
        print('temp',round(sum(days) / len(days), 2), end='; ')
        days.clear()

print("")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В смысле "просто так"? Вы же сами внутри цикла удаляете элементы из temps с помощью метода pop.

Comment: Ну их еще должно остаться на две недели. Посмотрите на выведенный список, там больше 14 дней.

Comment: Нельзя просто так итерироваться по коллекции, и одновременно модифицировать ее (и думать, что все при этом будет нормально работать). Уберите строку с `pop` и добавляйте в `days` просто переменную `temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    a = temps.pop()
    days.append(a)
```

Зачем это всё, если у вас есть переменная цикла, в которой перебирается коллекция? Замените эти строки на:

```py
    days.append(temp)
```

Изменять в цикле коллекцию, по которой вы итерируетесь - прямой путь к непоняткам.

Если всё же хотите сохранить внутреннюю логику цикла с `pop`, то просто итерируйтесь по копии списка, тогда всё, что внутри цикла можно не менять:

```py
for temp in temps.copy():
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда я специально хотел через pop, но ладно. А почему так происходит?

Comment: Подождите, тогда получается и список можно будет не переворачивать?

Comment: @TailsMan, представьте, что вы бежите в коридоре по ковру, и на каждом вашем шаге ковер из под вас слегка выдергивают. В итоге ковер закончится раньше, чем вы добежите до конца коридора. Нужно делать одно из двух - или бежать, но не трогать ковер (использовать for без pop), либо дергать ковер, но не бежать (использовать pop и цикл while, пока элементы не закончатся)

Comment: @TailsMan Насчёт переворота не знаю, это надо с логикой вашего алгоритма разбираться )  Как оставить `pop` я написал.